# Annoying Python Image.pixel method issue

Tags: python, image, module, pycharm

so I'm just trying to learn how to use the Image module and for some reason PyCharm won't recognize the Image.Pixel method, even after I've imported the Image module. An easy question, I'm sure, but What am I doing wrong here? (I've installed PIL)

```
from PIL import Image

p = Image.Pixel(45, 76, 200)

print(p.getRed())
```

PyCharm tells me 'ImportError: No module named 'Pixel', but from what I've read here (http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/thinkcspy/MoreAboutIteration/2DimensionalIterationImageProcessing.html#image-objects), I don't really see why this isn't working...

thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Look at the link you provided again. First you need to open some image, and then use image instance, to access pixels. Also, better to use pillow, than old PIL.

Comment: in my PyCharm's project interpreter, i've downloaded the Pillow package, but when I type 'from Pillow import Image' or even just 'import Pillow', i get a ImportError: No module named 'Pillow'. what am i doing wrong here? thanks for helping with such a trivial issue.

Comment: pillow is a drop-in replacement for PIL, so you still use `from PIL import Image`

Comment: thanks for all the help Marcin! just another question, kind of unrelated but think you might know how to help:
so i'm trying to download cImage.py from github (https://github.com/bnmnetp/cImage) to my PyCharm, but have no experience downloading into the Project Interpreter. I've gone as far as saving the raw github fie to my desktop, try to "add local" in PyCharm and select that file, but nothing changes. Any advice? thanks a bunch!

Comment: Sorry, I have newer used PyCharm, so cant help. I use PyDev.